# Rendering a GeoTiff file as an overlay on a map file

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers, geotiff

I'm using OpenLayers to render a GeoTiff file and now I want to display an ariel/satellite map as a baseLayer to it. The problem is that I can only render one layer for some reason,

here' my code

```
    const baseSource = new TileJSON({
      url: `https://api.maptiler.com/maps/hybrid/tiles.json?key=${key}`, 
      tileSize: 512,
      crossOrigin: "anonymous",
    });

    const baseLayer = new TileLayer({
      source: baseSource,
    });

    const source = new GeoTIFF({ sources: [{ url: props.src }] });
    const layer = new TileLayer({ source });


    const map = new Map({
      target: mapRef.current,
      layers: [baseLayer, layer],
      view: source.getView().then((viewConfig) => {
        viewConfig.showFullExtent = true;
        viewConfig.zoom = 0;
        viewConfig.center = [0, 0];

        return viewConfig;
      }),
    });

    map.on("loadstart", function () {
      if (spinRef.current?.style) spinRef.current.style.display = "inline-bock";
    });
    map.on("loadend", function () {
      if (spinRef.current?.style) spinRef.current.style.display = "none";
    });
```

This only renders the geoTiff file,
and when I do this

```
    const baseSource = new TileJSON({
      url: `https://api.maptiler.com/maps/hybrid/tiles.json?key=${key}`, 
      tileSize: 512,
      crossOrigin: "anonymous",
    });

    const baseLayer = new TileLayer({
      source: baseSource,
    });

    const source = new GeoTIFF({ sources: [{ url: props.src }] });
    const layer = new TileLayer({ source });


    const view = new View({
      constrainResolution: true,
      center: fromLonLat([5.0703139, 52.2250361]), 
      zoom: 14, 
    });
    const map = new Map({
      target: mapRef.current,
      layers: [baseLayer, layer],
      view,
    });
    layer.setOpacity(1);

    map.on("loadstart", function () {
      if (spinRef.current?.style) spinRef.current.style.display = "inline-bock";
    });
    map.on("loadend", function () {
      if (spinRef.current?.style) spinRef.current.style.display = "none";
    });
```

this only renders the baseLayer

Comment: The GeoTIFF if probably in a different projection which will need to be defined using proj4 as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/multiple-cogs.html - add `console.log(viewConfig..projection.getCode())` to find the projection then add the appropriate definition for it.

Comment: Hi, Mike your example does work, however there's just one more issue I'm facing I can't zoom out beyond the GeoTiff also can't move around either except within the geoTiff

Comment: That is because it was setting a view extent - you could remove that but the you would need to calculate an appropriate resolution https://codesandbox.io/s/fromepsgcode-forked-tzb1lp?file=/main.js  In the example the GeoTIFF is reprojected to the OSM projection (as would happen in your second code snippet).  It would also be possible to keep the GeoTIFF in its native projection and reproject the background (which would happen in your first snippet)

Answer (score 0):

From @mike comment example

```
import GeoTIFF from 'ol/source/GeoTIFF.js';
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/WebGLTile.js';
import proj4 from 'proj4';
import {fromEPSGCode, register} from 'ol/proj/proj4.js';
import {getCenter, getHeight, getWidth} from 'ol/extent.js';
import {transformExtent} from 'ol/proj.js';

register(proj4);

const sourceNames = ['B04', 'B03', 'B02', 'B08'];
const source = new GeoTIFF({
  sources: sourceNames.map(function (name) {
    return {
      url: `https://sentinel-cogs.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs/31/T/GJ/2022/7/S2A_31TGJ_20220703_0_L2A/${name}.tif`,
      max: 3000,
    };
  }),
});

const layer = new TileLayer({
  source: source,
});

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [new TileLayer({source: new OSM()}), layer],
  view: source.getView().then((viewConfig) => {
    return fromEPSGCode(viewConfig.projection.getCode()).then(() => {
      const projection = 'EPSG:3857';
      const extent = transformExtent(
        viewConfig.extent,
        viewConfig.projection,
        projection
      );
      const size = map.getSize();
      return {
        projection: projection,
        center: getCenter(extent),
        resolution: Math.max(
          getWidth(extent) / size[0],
          getHeight(extent) / size[1]
        ),
      };
    });
  }),
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).